# Method to calculate optimal nbasis (K) for fourier basis

Tags: r, fourier-transform, functional-data-analysis

Is there any method to calculate the optimal K for fourier basis transformation?
For example if I were to use RMSE, it seems that as K increases RMSE keeps going lower.
I'm thinking of the elbow-method from determining number of K clusters for K-means clustering.

But since I'm new to functional data analysis, I'm not sure whether there're better methods.

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(fda))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(fda.usc))
data(aemet,package = "fda.usc")
tt = aemet$temp$argvals
temp = as.data.frame(aemet$temp$data,row.names=F)
range.tt = aemet$temp$rangeval
inv.temp = data.frame(t(aemet$temp$data)) # 365 x 73 matrix
names(inv.temp) = aemet$df$name # Oviedo is the 10th column of inv.temp

temp_k7 = create.fourier.basis(rangeval = range(tt),nbasis = 7)
phimat = eval.basis(tt,basisobj=temp_k7)
phi.frame = data.frame(cbind(phimat,tt))
melt.phi = reshape::melt(data=phi.frame,id.vars="tt")

ovibasis5 = create.fourier.basis(rangeval = range(tt),nbasis = 5)
ovibasis50 = create.fourier.basis(rangeval = range(tt),nbasis = 50)
ovibasis121 = create.fourier.basis(rangeval = range(tt),nbasis = 121)
ovifourier5.fd = smooth.basis(argvals = tt, y = inv.temp[,10],fdParobj = ovibasis5)$fd
ovifourier51.fd = smooth.basis(argvals = tt, y = inv.temp[,10],fdParobj = ovibasis50)$fd
ovifourier121.fd = smooth.basis(argvals = tt, y = inv.temp[,10],fdParobj = ovibasis121)$fd
ovi5 = eval.fd(tt,ovifourier5.fd)
ovi51 = eval.fd(tt,ovifourier51.fd)
ovi121 = eval.fd(tt,ovifourier121.fd)
oviedo = setNames(data.frame(inv.temp[,10],ovi5,ovi51,ovi121),c("Oviedo","Fourier5","Fourier51","Fourier121"))

oviedo$tt <- tt

oviedotb <- pivot_longer(data = oviedo,cols = colnames(oviedo)[-5], names_to = 'type', values_to = 'value')

ggplot(oviedotb, aes(x = tt,y = value, color = type)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: Could you elaborate on the sense in which you intend "optimal" to be understood?

Comment: I think it's the same way how we intend to find the optimal number of cluster K for K-means. Yes, these are 2 different K, to be clear. In this context, as we increase K (nbasis), the resulting fourier basis K will start to overfit the actual raw data. 

If it makes sense, I want to find the optimal K such that we're not going to overfit and underfit the actual data.

Comment: Okay.  You might find it useful to search our site for threads on cross-validation and, more generally, overfitting.

Comment: I think the question is specific to functional data analysis. I'm looking for solution specifically for this FDA context as we don't have 'train' and 'test' split which is common with machine learning modeling.

Comment: Cross-validation doesn't work by means of a fixed split into training and testing data, so you might benefit by researching it further.

Comment: True, I'm not questioning the validity of cross-validation. Yes you can have fixed or multiple fold cross validation or rolling cross validation. Whatever, the question here is to know any available framework that can advise on the optimal nbasis K parameter for fourier basis smoothing. Hope that clarifies.